# Wiring a tankless water heater in shed

Tags: electrical, wiring, water-heater, tankless

I am installing a rheem RTEX-04 tankless water heater (120v 3.5kW) in a shed serviced by a sub-panel.  the installation manual says connect black to a 30a breaker, green to ground, and leave the red wire unconnected.  In the panel, the neutral and ground bars are separate - the ground bar being connected to an 8' ground rod.  Should I follow these installation instructions - they don't make sense to me.  I understand why the red wire is not needed (only need 120v), but it bothers me to not have a neutral return.
[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: That is really strange. I agree that the red wire must go to neutral (and should be white). I found the same manual on line and I cannot see how it got through Raheem’s QA department.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I will open the heater up and peek inside.  I got the manual online, but the one from Manassehkatz is definitely way better.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got those instructions from. They are *close* to the right stuff, but wrong in many small but *critical* ways. I found a much better [manual for the RTEX-04T at Home Depot](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/18/18812e3c-acc7-5516-9e7f-d095f9b447ce.pdf). There are a number of key differences. Maybe your copy was from before the engineers proofread it. Among the differences:

- For 6.5 kW (the 06 model, not yours but in the same manual and in your sample pages too), the voltage is listed as 240V, not 220V. That is important because it makes no sense for the manual to mix 120V with 220V. 110V and 220V - old but legitimate. 120V and 240V - modern numbers. 120V and 220V - nonsense.
- Also for 6.5 kW, lists 2x30A, not 1x30A.
- For both 3.5 kW and 6.5 kW, lists 2 x 10 AWG instead of 1 x 10 AWG. One wire makes no sense at all, as any circuit needs a return - whether neutral (120V) or 2nd hot (240V).
- The wiring diagram (page 8) clearly shows black to breaker, white neutral for 3.5 kW and black and red to double-pole breaker for 6.5 kW.

And now we get to the fun part. **These are basically the same machines.** They have the same manual - but that doesn't mean much - often several models of an appliance will share a manual. They are the exact same size - 6" x 11" x 3" and 4 lbs. They are the same price - $189 at Home Depot. So what's the difference? The heating element. That's it. Let's do the math:

- 120V, 29A, 3.5 kW - 4.14 Ohms
- 240V, 27A, 6.5 kW - 8.89 Ohms

I bet if you got parts diagrams for these two, almost the only difference would be the replacement heating elements.

Unless your load calculation/feed size for the shed simply doesn't allow for 30A at 240V, I highly recommend you swap the 3.5 kW for the 6.5 kW. You will get almost twice as much hot water, with no increase in the cost of the heater or the installation (same wires, same water connections). Yes, you'll pay for heating the water, but this is a small heater no matter what - you're using this to wash your hands or clean a few paint brushes or whatever, not to take a shower or wash dishes (I hope - you'll be really disappointed if you try.)

Comment: Downvoter care to explain what I got wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First an aside.  Your subpanel is set up incorrectly. As of NEC 2008, it must have a separate neutral and ground **wire** going back to the panel. Plus the 1 or 2 hot wires. If it is an outbuilding, it must have the ground rods as well.

A lot of people think "well if it has the ground rods, that saves me a ground wire, because the dirt can conduct as well as a copper wire".  Only if your town was built on a giant copper nugget.

If the subpanel was wired without a separate neutral and ground, legal prior to NEC 2008, then you must combine neutral and ground on the neutral wire, which means bonding neutral and ground in the sub.  This [has issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE), which is why it was banned.

Now either the heater instructions are confused, or you are.  The heater definitely needs a 2-wire loop (other than ground).  In 120V, this is hot to neutral, and neutral must be native white.  In 240V, this is L1 to L2.  L2 can be white remarked a color *if it is in a cable*.  That's how we avoid having to make and stock black-red-bare cables.  Black is a fine color, does not need to be red.

- Legal colors neutral: white or gray
- Legal colors ground: green, yellow/green, or bare
- Legal colors L1: all except white, gray, green, yellow-green
- Legal colors L2: all except white, gray, green, yellow-green